# How can I assign section numbers automatically?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, table-of-contents

I have my sections labeled only in words, using the appropriate header hierarchy. My top level headers are header 1. Their children are header 2. Their children are header 3. etc.

When I build my table of contents, where I currently have

```
Orientation...................1
   Necessary forms............2
   Parking pass...............4
Benefits......................5
   Healthcare.................6
   Whipping post..............8
```

I want it to automatically assign numberings to those, like

```
1) Orientation................1
   1.1) Necessary forms.......2
   1.2) Parking pass..........4
2) Benefits...................5
   2.1) Healthcare............6
   2.2) Whipping post.........8
```

Is there any way I can do this? I don't want to have to update the numbers manually when Benefits becomes section 3 and Workplace Expectations is the new section 2.

Answer (score 2):

This is something that has been driving Word users mad forever!

1) Make sure that your heading style are set up correctly. Heading 1 should not be based on anything or based on Normal style. All other heading styles should be based on the heading level above it. E.g. Heading 2 based on Heading 1, etc. Simply Modify the appropriate style to see what it is based on.

2) Chose an existing multi-level list or create a new one. Click on the drop down for multi-level lists. This is to the right of the numbered list button. Best to create a new multi-level list called Headings or some such.

3) Go through levels 1 to 9 of the list and associate that level with the appropriate Heading style you are using - normally just Heading 1, Heading 2, etc. However, this is also how you can create numbered Appendix headings too. Create new styles for Appendix headings and then a new Appendix list type and match the two.

4) When configuring the list, don't forget to make the intents match what you want.

When doing this, you have the choice as to whether you want the changes stored in the normal.dot default template or in a document template. If you want to be able to give the same settings to other people without messing up their own preferences, start by creating a blank document, make the changes but ensure that you are saving them to the document not normal.dot and then save as a template document.

As a final note, lists in Word are fundamentally and badly broken and always have been. Even 2013 doesn't fix that. If you've ever worked on a really big structured document that lots of people have worked on and that gathers information from many sources, you will find out the hard way that Word eventually blows up in your face. Either the document gets irrevocably corrupt or it looses most or all of its formatting. When working on documents like that I override the SAVE function with one that makes a backup copy of the previous version BEFORE saving the new copy & I keep at least a dozen versions. I've discovered that the hard way, I recommend you avoid it!

Comment: So it has to be baked into the "numbered list" functionality? It seems this is something a bit larger scoped than just a list. Crossword clue, starts with W, 4 letters, synonym for expensive disappointment...

Comment: Actually, it's worse! It has to be baked into BOTH the numbered list AND the heading style! Fully agree with your synonym! The good news, sort of, is that once you've done it, it is reasonably portable to new documents, at least via the document template.

Comment: @JulianKnight - how did you "override the SAVE function with one that makes a backup copy of the previous version BEFORE saving the new copy"? Because I need this.

Comment: Details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837542.aspx just replace the command with a macro of the same name.